# Trim the string data fetched from the table in delphi using ado dataset

Tags: delphi

I have got a table column of datatype char and by making use of ADO dataset I am fetching the data. But because of type char, it displays the data with trailing extra spaces. And the form on which this ADO dataset lies is inherited by many forms. I want to trim the extra spaces by making  some change in the Delphi code on parent form by using some ADO dataset property

I have made use of FixedChar property of the data field by making it to false but that did not work

Comment: is it possible to change the datatype in the database ? I cant remember ever needing a column with type char

Comment: No unfortunately it is not possible to change datatype in database

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Cast(mycharcolumn as varchar(10)) as mynewcharcolumn from tablename
```

If you can change the query that retrieves the data, like I've shown here, then you effectively convert your char columns to varchar columns at the dataset level.

If you are unable to make changes to the query, then another way is to add a calculated column to the `Tfield` list of the dataset, and in the OnCalcFields event handler, you can `Trim(mycharcolumn)` to 'calculate' the value of the calculated field, which you then use in the code, in place of the original field.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the OnGetText event of the field and trim the text:

```
procedure TMyForm.AdoDataSet1GetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  Text := Trim(Text);
end;
```